# Spring JSON POST image

Tags: json, spring

I tried to find how I can POST an image from JSON response to the server(save to the server side). How I've understood, I can use **@RequestBody**, but I don't know how I can do this. Thanx for any help from you.

Comment: Unless you post your code and also tell us what you have tried, I am going to post description of 'How to make chicken and mushroom soup' as an answer..

Comment: I just want a simple example how I can recieve an image from JSON.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you asking how to POST an image in a JSON request body to the server? I have done this recently, see the details [here](http://thoughtfulsoftware.blogspot.com/2012/12/uploading-binary-files-fun-way.html). I provided this answer in [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615692/how-do-i-upload-stream-large-images-using-spring-3-2-spring-mvc-in-a-restful-way/14617556#14617556), but will replicate the answer here.

On the browser we can make use of the file API to load a file, then encode its contents using Base64 encoding, and finally assign the encoded contents to a javascript object before posting it.

On the server, we have a Spring Controller which will handle the request. As part of the json unmarshalling that converts the the request body to a java object, the base64-encoded value for the image bytes will be converted to a standard Java byte[], and stored as a LOB in the database or streamed as a byte array directly to disk (depending on how you want to save the file on the server)

To retrieve the image, another Spring Controller method can provide the image by streaming the bytes back directly.

The blog post I linked to above presumes you want to use the image as part of another object, but the principle should be the same if you want to only work with the image directly. Since you want the image to be part of a JSON request body, it sounds like this technique is what you want, though. Let me know if anything needs clarification.

Comment: Thanx Jay. I've just read about Base64. But how it will look like in URL if it will be Base64 string :) In the database images will save as URLs. And i'm going to do image as a part of the @RequestBody.

Comment: The base 64 string is part of the request body, not part of the URL, so you won't see it. Also it doesn't make a lot of sense to save a URL in the database when you are trying to save the actual image. You should clear up the schema you have in mind for how to store these images.

Comment: I'm going to store these images directly to disk. I don't know, is this right, that request body looks like '{"image": "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4QITRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgACgEDAAMAAAABAAYAAAEPAAIAAAAIAAAAhgEQAAIAAAAJAAAAjgESAAMAAAABAAEAAAEaAAUAAAABAAAAlwEbAAUAAAABAAAAnwEoAAMAAAABAAIAAAEyAAIAAAAUAAAApwITAAMAAAABAAEAAIdpAAQAAAABAAAAuwAAAABTQU1TVU5H/hJ8SBaiabTruG3J56r4b09nZxGzAFUCDkdOoauXuNH8H+MtR8rVrVJpYsqjsgYgc5xlWx09a55YtbnqwpNn/2Q=="}', it's not even placed here .... ?

Comment: yes, that's what I'd expect an image encoded in a json request body to look like.

Comment: So, can I do like this?It's not very nice view, as I think

Comment: Using the sample code in the post, my payload looks like this: {"image":{"bytes":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYA ... 2Q==", "contentType":"image/jpeg"}} Not sure what you mean by not a very nice view.

Comment: Thank you.I've meant very big size of request body.